# Dedupe drawing objects in SVG/vector graphics files

Tags: pdf, libreoffice, svg, inkscape

I have an exported image consisting of ~35000 objects (the only way to get it out of the source application was as a copy-pasted "metafile").  By pasting into libreoffice draw and converting to polygons I have something I can edit.  Each visible line in the file is a stack of 8 lines, so there are 8x as many objects as there should be.  At the moment it crashes inkscape, either as a .pdf or .svg,  but I can edit in libreoffice (it's painfully slow to do anything like pan or zoom, and manual deduping would be 10-20 hours work by my rough calculation).

Is there anything out there that can read an SVG file, find objects which are duplicates of each other and keep just 1 of the copies?  The vast majority of my objects are lines, so if it could only handle lines not polygons that would get my file down to a useable size.

As an SVG the file is 20MB, obviously .odg and .pdf are compressed.

I've got linux or winXP (VM, don't ask!) at my disposal.

Comment: On inspecting the file, I notice lots of objects with rgb(255,255,255) fill - getting rid of those wouldn't hurt. A stub of something to start from in Python might be enough to get me going.

Comment: getting rid of the white objects (previous comment) was easy with a regexp in notepad++, but although the SVG is now 1/3 smaller it still kills inkscape.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well it turns out working with XML in python is pretty easy.  The following code recursively  (to deal with nested groups)  runs over the file.  A hash of each path (some of the paths are pretty long) is stored, unless the hash is a duplicate, in which case the node is marked for deletion.  Actual deletion happens before going back up to the parent as it appears to break the iteration over the children if done on the fly.
Deletion of white-filled objects is in there too.

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import hashlib as hash

def iter_groups(group):
    global hashlist
    global count
    rem=[]
    for child in group:
        if child.tag==rtag+'g' :#we have a group
            iter_groups(child)
        else:
            if child.tag==rtag+'path':
                h=hash.md5(str(child.attrib)).hexdigest()
                print h
                if h in hashlist:
                    rem.append(child)
                    print "removing ",child.tag, "in",group.tag,group.attrib," -- duplicate"
                    count+=1
                else:
                    try:
                        print child.attrib['fill']
                    except KeyError:
                        print 'no fill'
                        #no fill attribute
                    else:
                        if ("rgb(255,255,255)") in child.attrib['fill']:
                            rem.append(child)
                            print "removing ",child.tag, "in",group.tag,group.attrib," -- white"
                        else:
                            hashlist.append(h)
    for r in rem: group.remove(r)

#main#
hashlist=[] 
count=0 
tree = ET.parse('imgtest.svg')
root = tree.getroot()
rtag= root.tag.split('}')[0]+'}'
iter_groups(root)       
tree.write('imgtest_out.svg',encoding="us-ascii", xml_declaration=True, default_namespace="", method="xml")
```

Issues:

- For some reason all tags in the output are prepended with "ns0:" -- find&replace fixes that
- You might be left with lots of empty groups, and unreferenced ids -- running [scour](http://www.codedread.com/scour) over the file afterwards (with `--enable-id-stripping`) is a good idea.

Results:
initial file: 20,030KB
after this code: 8,555KB
after scour: 4,545KB
this is just about workable in inkscape.

There are still a few visual duplicates produced by marginally different code, and still some functionally empty groups.

**Edit** the above code had several bugs, not least that it didn't actually remove the white objects.  I've also hacked together something to deal with empty groups and groups containing only 1 element.  It's ugly but here it is anyway.

```
import xml.etree.cElementTree as ET
import hashlib as hash
import copy

def get_attr(obj,attr):
    try:
        return obj.attrib[attr]
    except KeyError:
        return None
    else:
        return None

def iter_groups(group):
    global hashlist
    global count
    rem=[]
    for child in group:
        if child.tag==rtag+'g' :#we have a group
            iter_groups(child)
        else:
            if child.tag==rtag+'path':
                h=hash.md5(str(child.attrib)).hexdigest()
                print h
                if h in hashlist:
                    rem.append(child)
                    print "removing ",child.tag, "in",group.tag,group.attrib," -- duplicate"
                    count+=1
                else:   
                    if get_attr(child,'fill')!=None:
                        if ("rgb(255,255,255)") in child.attrib['fill']:
                            print "removing ",get_attr(child,'id'), "in",group.tag,group.attrib," -- white"
                            rem.append(child)
                        else:
                            hashlist.append(h)
    for r in rem: 
        print "about to remove",r.attrib
        group.remove(r)
    rem=[]
    for child in group:
        if child.tag==rtag+'g' :#we have a group
            if len(child.findall('*'))==0:
                print "removing ",child.tag, "in",group.tag,group.attrib," -- empty"
                rem.append(child)
    for r in rem: group.remove(r)


def ungroup_singles(group):
    global count
    for child in group:
        #print child.tag,rtag
        if child.tag==rtag+'g' :#we have a group
            print "len(group",get_attr(child,'id'),")",len(child)
            if len(child)>1:
                ungroup_singles(child)
            else :
                if len(child)==1:
                    if (len(child[0])>=1)or(child[0].tag<>rtag+'g'):
                        print "about to promote",child[0].tag,get_attr(child[0],'id'),get_attr(child[0],'class')
                        print len(child[0])
                        moveelem=copy.deepcopy(child[0])
                        group.append(moveelem)
                        group.remove(child)
                        count+=1
                    else:
                        print "about to remove",child[0].tag,get_attr(child[0],'id'),get_attr(child[0],'class')
                    child.remove(child[0])
                    count+=1
                else:#i.e. len(child)==0
                    print "about to remove",child.tag,get_attr(child,'id'),get_attr(child,'class')
                    group.remove(child)
                    count+=1
        #else:
            # if gl==1:#and not clipped?
                #moveelem= ET.copy.deepcopy(child)

#main#
hashlist=[] 
count=0 
ET.register_namespace("","http://www.w3.org/2000/svg")
tree = ET.parse('imgtest_l.svg')
root = tree.getroot()
rtag= root.tag.split('}')[0]+'}'
iter_groups(root)
print "A", count," elements removed"
lcount=1
while True:
    count=0
    ungroup_singles(root)
    print lcount,":",count," empty groups removed / single elements promoted from groups"
    lcount+=1
    if count==0 or lcount>10:
        break

tree.write('imgtest_out.svg',encoding="us-ascii", xml_declaration=True, default_namespace="", method="xml")
```